# Setting text color and background color assembly language x86 (masm)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

```
    .data
myname byte "Ngoche Penpa Gyaltsen",0
space byte ' ',0

.code

main PROC
    mov esi,0
    mov eax,0
    mov ecx,lengthof myname
    mov edx,offset space

L1:
movzx eax,myname[esi]
call writechar

mov eax,16
mov eax,yellow +(blue*16)
call settextcolor
call writestring
inc esi
loop L1;

exit
```

My question here is why do we need to set `mov eax,0` and `mov esi,0`. Also, `mov eax,16` is it mandatory before `mov eax,textcolor +(background)` because when I run without this my program shows an error. In addition, I want to learn more about masm counter and coloring in program. Can anyone suggest me site where I can practice and solved programming exercises.

Comment: any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for the `mov eax, 0`, because the value will be overwritten by the following `movzx` instruction. The `mov esi, 0` is required because the `esi` register is used to index into the `myname` array.

There is no need for the `mov eax,16`, because the value is overwritten by the very next instruction. Are you sure that removing that line causes an error? It sure doesn't look like it should.

Comment: if I write like mov al,myname[esi] that's only time I write mov eax,0? mov eax,16 is not needed you are right. another question pls. what is the meaning of push and pop?                            push eax
  mov eax,300
  call delay
  
  mov eax,16
  call randomrange
  inc eax
  mov textcolor,eax
  mov eax,(textcolor+(blue*15))
  call settextcolor
 pop eax
 inc esi
 inc dh

Comment: @PenpaGyaltsen: You need an x86 assembler tutorial. Check out http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html